# Script just fires when keys are pressed in specific order

Tags: autohotkey

In below script I'm not defining `~l::` as this is used as part of another script.

so if I re-define `~l::` I receive error when try to add this script :

[image]

Below script does not fire if the "el" is pressed but it does fire
if "le" is pressed :

```
~e::
If (GetKeyState("e","p") & GetKeyState("l","p")) {
    Run "C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
}
Return
```

Why is this occuring ? Could another script be impacting the behaviour of this script ?

Update :

Entire script :

```
~l::
If (GetKeyState("c","p") && GetKeyState("l","p")) {
    Send, {Backspace Down}{Backspace Up}{Backspace Down}{Backspace Up}
    Run, "www.google.com"
}
Return

;##################################################

;######################################## Eclipse ########
~e::
If (GetKeyState("e","p") & GetKeyState("l","p")) {
    Run "C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
}
Return
```

Comment: Please post your whole script, at least up until line 25 or so.

Comment: @MCL I've posted entire script. Commented out code has been removed from script which is why "line 25" is not matching script line.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error using your code. Is there something else to it, that is, can you post an example which fails with the same error?

Comment: @MCL im not trying to fix the error. I was just pointing out why the error occurs. I'm trying to ensure that when "el" is pressed " Run "C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my script to top of page and now it works :

```
~e::
~l::
If (GetKeyState("e","p") && GetKeyState("l","p")) {
    Run "C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
}
Return ;
```